# Attach user id to a post (Laravel 5.3)

Tags: laravel, laravel-5

in my app I want to attach a logged in user id to a post, below is my controller :

```
public function storejournal(JournalRequest $request) {
        $input = $request->all();

        //Input PDF
        if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
            $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
        }

        //Insert data jurnal
        $id = $request->id;
        $journal = Edition::findOrFail($id)->journal()->create($input);
        $journal->user_id = Auth::id();
        $journal->user()->attach($request->input('penulis'));

        return redirect()->route('edition', ['id' => $id]);
    }
```

I tried the above controller it gave error : `SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 1364 Field 'user_id' doesn't have a default value (SQL: insert into`journal`(`title`,`abstract`,`file`,`id_edition`,`journalslug`,`updated_at`,`created_at`) values (Rancang bangun website Jurnal Online jurusan Teknik Informatika Universitas Palangkaraya, ddd, test3.pdf, 1, rancang-bangun-website-jurnal-online-jurusan-teknik-informatika-universitas-palangkaraya, 2016-11-15 03:43:34, 2016-11-15 03:43:34))`

I don't understand what I did wrong, if someone can help that would be great. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're trying to create a Journal without specifying the `user_id` when it's created.

I'd suggest the following:

```
public function storejournal(JournalRequest $request) {
    $input = $request->all();

    //Input PDF
    if ($request->hasFile('file')) {
        $input['file'] = $this->uploadPDF($request);
    }

    //Insert data jurnal
    $id = $request->id;
    $journal = Edition::findOrFail($id)->journal()->create($input + ['user_id' => Auth::id()]);
    $journal->user()->attach($request->input('penulis'));

    return redirect()->route('edition', ['id' => $id]);
}
```

Also, don't forget to have `user_id` set as mass assignable in the Journal class.

Comment: The problem is really simple, you're right I forgot to set the "user_id" as mass assignable in the Journal class, my bad my bad..

Answer (score 2):

The error says you should pass `user_id` too. You can do this with adding user ID to an `$input`:

```
$input = $request->all();
$input['user_id'] = auth()->user()->id;
```

Comment: still get the same error :( .. note : I have multiple relations between these two tables (users and journal) the first one is many-to-many relationship that are connected using a pivot table and the second one is one-to-many relationship without using a pivot table

Comment: It's working now, seems like the problem is I forgot to set the "user_id" field as mass assignable in the Journal Class, my bad.